# How can I add two conditions to the add_async_defer function for google maps?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

The add_sync_defer function as required for google maps normally looks like this:

```
//For Google Maps API
    function add_async_defer($tag, $handle) {
    if('googlemaps' !== $handle) {
        return $tag;
    }
    return str_replace(' src', 'async="async" defer="defer" src', $tag);
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_defer', 10, 2);
```

However I am trying to run two google maps on my Wordpress site (two different zoom levels, two different pages) and it's been a pain in the rear to get it working, but it works... sometimes.  I couldn't get it to work with any kind of conditional statement that included two conditions, something like the following:

```
//For Google Maps API
function add_async_defer($tag, $handle) {
    if(('googlemaps1' !== $handle) || ('googlemaps2' !== $handle)) {
        return $tag;
    }
    return str_replace(' src', 'async="async" defer="defer" src', $tag);
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_defer', 10, 2);
```

This resulted in white space where the maps should be.  I then tried having two functions, one for each map, but this results in white space a lot of the time or the map loading normally.  Something like the following:

```
//For Google Maps API
function add_async_defer1($tag, $handle) {
    if('googlemaps1' !== $handle) {
        return $tag;
    }
    return str_replace(' src', 'async="async" defer="defer" src', $tag);
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_defer1', 10, 2);
```

(and the same for add_async_defer2)

Any pointers as to why these things are happening?  I'd prefer to only have one async defer function and also just one initMap function with parameters passed in but I couldn't find a way to do that for the purpose of having two different maps (initMap is called by the googlemaps string, no parameters can be passed there as far as I know, setting the zoom based on the page sounds like the way to go but how to get that zoom setting as set on my custom theme options page into the initMap function correctly?)

Comment: The use case is unclear. Why do you use these functions at all? What didn't work? Why? Are you attempting to load the Maps API script twice (which isn't needed) and if yes, why? You need to provide a clear description of the issue as well as a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding if statements in the functions.php file -

```
if ( is_page('contact')) { wp_register_script('googlemaps1'...etc) }
if ( is_page('about')) { wp_register_script('googlemaps2'...etc) }
```

thus loading the googlemaps scripts only on the specific pages required, there must have been a conflict as it was attempting to load both map APIs to every page.  Now all errors in the console log are cleared and the maps appear to load every time I refresh the page or clear the cache.

I also added if statements around the wp_enqueue lines:

```
if ( is_page('contact')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps1');
    }

    if ( is_page('about')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps2');
    }
```

The two conditions in the if statement in the add_async_defer function now work as expected:

```
function add_async_defer($tag, $handle) {
    if(('googlemaps1' !== $handle) && ('googlemaps2' !== $handle)) {
        return $tag;
    }
    return str_replace(' src', 'async="async" defer="defer" src', $tag);
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_defer', 10, 2);
```

For completeness, here's what I have in my scripts.js for the maps:

```
//Google Map Init 1
var map1;

function initMap1() {

  var latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat( options.latitude ),
    lng: parseFloat( options.longitude )
  }

  map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: parseInt( options.zoom1 ),
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map1,
    title: 'Here I am'
  });
}

//Google Map Init 2
var map2;

function initMap2() {

  var latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat( options.latitude ),
    lng: parseFloat( options.longitude )
  }

  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: parseInt( options.zoom2 ),
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map2,
    title: 'Here I am'
  });
}
```

I'm sure it's not optimal and I may be able to refactor it into a single function with variables, but until that happens I know this works.